# How to select the multiple outputs from a function?

Tags: dolphindb

I define a function by the following code:

```py
def func(Open,High,Low,Close,20)
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
return x,y
```

There are two return results in the function “func()”, and I want to select these two results in one select clause. I write a statement as follows:

```py
t=select TimeStamp,funcA(Open,High,Low,Close,20) as factorA,funcB(Open,High,Low,Close,20) as factorB, from xxx
```

The function is called twice in a select clause which will waste more time. Is there a method to get these two results by calling the function only once?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the select clause like this: select ...as `factor1`factor2

```py
t=table(take(now(),3) as TimeStamp, 1..3 as Open, 1..3 as High, 1..3 as Close, 1..3 as Low)
def func(Open, High, Low, Close, num) {
    x=avg(Open)
    y=max(High)
    return x, y
}
select TimeStamp, func(Open, High, Low, Close, 20) as `factor1`factor2 from t
```

| TimeStamp | factor1 | factor2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021.09.18T17:10:04.969 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021.09.18T17:10:04.969 | 2 | 3 |
| 2021.09.18T17:10:04.969 | 2 | 3 |